# ./a.out && echo $? only prints return value if return = 0

Tags: ubuntu, aix, echo, os390, exit-status

*echo $?* in the following scenario does not display the return value, i.e. 1.

```
echo "int main() { return 1; }" > foo.c
gcc foo.c && ./a.out && echo $?
```

However, *echo $?* works when the program returns 0. Why is this?

Note: If you do another *echo $?* after the code above, you get the desired output 1.

Comment: Because the semantics of `&&` is to only execute the second command if the first command returned 0.

Comment: If you want to run your `a.out` program and then print the return value (a.k.a. exit status) unconditionally, use `./a.out; echo $?`.

Comment: I would up vote but I don't have enough reps, thanks for the explanation and suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` operator is a boolean **and** with short-circuit evaluation. This means that it only executes the second command if the first one is successful (i.e. it returns `0`). A typical way it's used is something like this:

```
tar xf file.tar && rm file.tar
```

This only removes the file if the extraction is successful.

Your script also contains a good example of this:

```
gcc foo.c && ./a.out
```

will only try to run the program if `gcc` was successful.

If you want to display `$?` regardless of the success of `a.out`, you can write:

```
gcc foo.c && { ./a.out ; echo $? ; }
```

The `{...}` groups the command so they'll both be executed if the compilation is successful.